# pythonにおける要約のプログラムのエラー: Resource punkt not found

Tags: python

このエラーの対処が分からず、困っています。
教えて欲しいです。

【エラー】

```
 0%|          | 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s]0
  0%|          | 0/2 [00:06<?, ?it/s]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LookupError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sumy/nlp/tokenizers.py in _get_sentence_tokenizer(self, language)
    126             path = to_string("tokenizers/punkt/%s.pickle") % to_string(language)
--> 127             return nltk.data.load(path)
    128         except (LookupError, zipfile.BadZipfile) as e:

5 frames
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource punkt not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  >>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('punkt')
  
  Searched in:
    - '/root/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - ''
**********************************************************************


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

LookupError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sumy/nlp/tokenizers.py in _get_sentence_tokenizer(self, language)
    130                 "NLTK tokenizers are missing or the language is not supported.\n"
    131                 """Download them by following command: python -c "import nltk; nltk.download('punkt')"\n"""
--> 132                 "Original error was:\n" + str(e)
    133             )
    134 

LookupError: NLTK tokenizers are missing or the language is not supported.
Download them by following command: python -c "import nltk; nltk.download('punkt')"
Original error was:

**********************************************************************
  Resource punkt not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  >>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('punkt')
  
  Searched in:
    - '/root/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - ''
**********************************************************************
```

【コード】

```
#@title
import requests
import json
import csv
import pytz
import datetime
import tqdm
import numpy as np

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep

from google.colab import files

##############
### DEFINE ###
##############
#KEYWORD = "福祉"
#SLEEP_TIME = 0.5

url = 'https://api.jgrants-portal.go.jp/exp/v1/public/subsidies?keyword=' + keyword + '&sort=created_date&order=DESC&acceptance=1'
req = requests.get(url)
reqJSON = json.loads(req.text)

# resultデータのループ
csvList = []
ID = []
for i in tqdm.tqdm(range(len(reqJSON["result"]))):
  # tqdm
  np.pi*np.pi
  if i % 1e6 == 0:
    print(i)

  # csv書き込み用リストにヘッダー行を追加
  resultData=reqJSON["result"][i]
  csvRow = []
  csvRow.append(resultData["title"])
  csvRow.append(resultData["id"])
  csvRow.append(resultData["acceptance_start_datetime"])
  csvRow.append(resultData["acceptance_end_datetime"])
  csvRow.append(resultData["subsidy_max_limit"])
  csvRow.append(resultData["target_area_search"])
  csvRow.append(resultData["target_number_of_employees"])

  # selenium,Chromedriverの定義
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument('--headless')
  options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
  wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)

  # IDに格納したIDリストをもとにHPを開けてスクレイピング
  tURL = "https://www.jgrants-portal.go.jp/subsidy/" + resultData["id"]
  wd.get(tURL)
  sleep(sleep_time)
  detail = wd.find_element(by=By.TAG_NAME, value="table").text

  # Load Packages
  from sumy.parsers.plaintext import PlaintextParser
  from sumy.nlp.tokenizers import Tokenizer
  # For Strings
  parser = PlaintextParser.from_string(detail,Tokenizer("english"))
  from sumy.summarizers.text_rank import TextRankSummarizer
  # Summarize using sumy TextRank
  summarizer = TextRankSummarizer()
  summary =summarizer_4(parser.document,2)
  text_summary=""
  for sentence in summary:
      text_summary+=str(sentence)
  print(text_summary)

  # csv書き込み用リストに詳細を追加
  csvRow.append(detail)
  csvRow.append(text_summary)

  # tURLを追加
  csvRow.append(tURL)

  # 1行を1要素として配列に保存
  csvList.append(csvRow)

wd.close()

# 新規CSVファイルの作成
csv_date = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Tokyo')).strftime("%Y%m%d")
csv_file_name = ( keyword + "jGrants" + csv_date + ".csv")
f = open(csv_file_name, "w", encoding="Shift-jis", errors="ignore")#windowsの場合encoding=Shift-js

# csvファイルへの書き込み
writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator="\n") 
csv_header = ["タイトル","ID","開始日","終了日","金額の上限","対象地域","対象となる従業員数","詳細","要約","URL"]
writer.writerow(csv_header)
for csvData in csvList:
  writer.writerow(csvData)
f.close()

# csvファイル出力
files.download(csv_file_name)
```

Comment: このサイトの記事内容はMarkdownという記法で色々と装飾されて表示されます。[Markdown や HTML を使用して投稿を書式設定するには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) 貴方が見易いと考えて工夫したテキストは、それによってかえって見難くなったり、何処から何処までが何の説明かの区別が出来なくなったりしています。それから「このエラーの対処が分からず、困っています。」だけでは、このプログラムがどんなもので、どんなOS/開発ツール/版数で動かしていて、なにをしたい/どうなって欲しいか、自分では何を調べたか、といったことの説明が不足しているようです。また必要とするデータやCSVファイルと言ったものも提示してください。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: エラーメッセージの通り、`python -c "import nltk; nltk.download('punkt')"`コマンドを実行して[NLTK環境を構築する](https://qiita.com/ldap2017/items/158a9aa5ec330e907197)と、このエラー自体は解消しますか？

Answer (score 1):

@payaneco さんがコメントされたように、[NLTK環境を構築する](https://qiita.com/ldap2017/items/158a9aa5ec330e907197)で解説されている`python -c "import nltk; nltk.download()"`を実行することで質問のエラーは発生しなくなるようです。
Windows10の環境で確認しました。

ちなみにWindows10なので`from google.colab import files`と`files.download(csv_file_name)`はコメントアウトしています。

---

そして他にはコメントアウトされていた以下2行のコメントを外し、変数名を小文字にする必要がありました。こちらを：

```
#KEYWORD = "福祉"
#SLEEP_TIME = 0.5
```

こちらに変更しました。

```
keyword = "福祉"
sleep_time = 0.5
```

---

さらに、以下に抜粋した下の行の`summarizer_4`は質問時の転記ミスか何かの様で、そのような名前は無いとエラーになったので`summarizer`としたら動作しました。

```
  summarizer = TextRankSummarizer()
  summary =summarizer_4(parser.document,2)
```

---

なお、プログラムの途中で import している`sumy`というパッケージが更に内部で import しているパッケージの機能(`from collections import Sequence`だったか)が原因で、Python 3.8 以後では動作しないようです。(少なくともPython 3.10では動きませんでした。それ以前では警告で済むのかもしれませんね)